# Deactivate WooCommerce shop base

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Since I am only selling one single product with WooCommerce, I would like to delete the shop base. I have already deleted the page "shop" which WooCommerce automatically sets up when installing, but you can still reach the shop base page by typing .../shop.

I know in order to deactivate it completely, I need to set line 264 to false:
https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-post-types.php#L264

I am very new to programming though, can someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: A workaround would be to use `template_redirect` hook and check inside if the page being requested is the shop page with `is_shop()` , if it is then redirect to another page or take appropriate action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following code to your child theme's functions.php file

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_shop' );

function redirect_shop() {
    if( is_shop() ) {
        //replace the link below to point to your single product page
        header('location:http://www.example.com/');
        exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the you do not need `archieve.php` template in your site, so can restrict this template to be executed and as @Anand Shah has said you can also display content `if ( !is_shop() )`, that means when the page is not shop.how you want it to be done , that matters, there is a  lot of ways to do this.

Comment: Sorry, like I mentioned I don't know anything about programming but Woocommerce support said to set line 264 in the above linked file to false, so xould you please let me know what I need to do?

Comment: change ` 'rewrite'             => $product_permalink ? array( 'slug' => untrailingslashit( $product_permalink ), 'with_front' => false, 'feeds' => true ) : false,` to  `'rewrite' => false;` but this is not the correct way to achieve this as when you will update your woocommerce , It will again show shop page.youshould consider doing  the stuffs in functions.php

Comment: Thank you, I understand what you are saying and if using a function  in my child theme makes this update safe, I WOULD PREFER THAT. But again, I don't know how to use filters and hooks...

Comment: Anand Shah has suggested one good trick, you can redirect the shop page to some other page , that can be used or what helgatheviking has said is what you got from the github that is same as what you are asked to do, but if it is not working, you may need a  few changes and it will definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

Just a few lines above the line you referenced, you can see that all the arguments for registering the product post type are sent through the [`woocommerce_register_post_type_product`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-post-types.php#L234) filter, which means that you can modify any of the values. To disable the `shop` archive you need to set `has_archive` to false from a new plugin or your theme's functions.php (less ideal).

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_register_post_type_product', 'so_32921498_product_post_type_args' );
function so_32921498_product_post_type_args($args){
    $args['has_archive'] = false;
    return $args;
}
```

Comment: This code does not work unfortunately. I tried it in my chiod theme's functions but the shop page is still visible. The only thing that works is           add_action('template_redirect', 'remove_wp_shop');
function remove_wp_shop(){
  if( is_shop() ) {
    global $wp_query;
    $wp_query->set_404();
  }
}

Comment: But how can I redirrect it to my single product instead of 404?

Comment: Oops, that should have been `has_archive` to kill the archive. That does not redirect though, which isn't in your original question. The `template_redirect` method will work well.